# Perl, recursive find and replace from list in text file?

Tags: perl, recursion

Good morning!  I am learning perl on the fly.  Yay, learning!

I have ~650 .xml files.  I have ~ 400 pairs of strings to find and replace through those .xml files.  The strings are currently in a tab delimited text file.    I need to replace the 7 characters on the left, with Figure blah blah blah for each pair.

```
FCN.D75 Figure 0001. Air Compressor
FCN.D90 Figure 0002. Air Compressor Cooling Lines
FCN.D84 Figure 0003. Air Compressor Supply Lines
```

I have seen several solutions on how to find and replace from a list in a file, and several solutions on how to find and replace recursively through a directory, but not the magic combination.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Dan

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow isn't the best place to ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (you need to install File::Slurper or emulate its subs by yourself):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Find qw( find );
use File::Slurper qw( read_lines read_text write_text );

my %phrases = map {
    split m/\s/, $_, 2
} read_lines( 'phrases_list.txt' );

find(
    {
        no_chdir => 1,
        wanted   => sub {
            my $file_path = $File::Find::name;
            next if $file_path !~ m/\.xml$/;
            next unless -f $file_path;

            my $text = read_text( $file_path );
            $text =~ s/\Q$_\E/$phrases{$_}/ge for keys %phrases;
            write_text( $file_path, $text );
        },
    },
    '.'
);
```

Comment: @Dan, If this helped, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks!